# What is the meaning of "formalism" in a scientific paper? What is the structure of such paper?

Tags: publications, computer-science, methodology

I see some papers that aim to present a **formalism** for something. First, what probably they are going to do? (for example in the field of computer science) Second, what is the methodology and main structure of such papers (which sections do they need)?

Comment: What research field is this referring to?

Comment: @eykanal it is in the tags of the question, computer science

Comment: As this question seems to be fairly domain-specific, I suggest migrating it to the CS SE site. Also, I would like to mention that term _formalism_ IMHO has several interpretations, including, at least, two science-related: [a philosophical one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_%28mathematics%29) and its mathematical perspective (which the OP is likely interested in).

Comment: You seem to be asking many different questions at once. May I suggest that you restrict yourself to the question of what a *formalism* is and whether what you propose is one?

Comment: This question, as far as I understand it, seems very specific to your writing project. I don't think that this site offers the specific tutoring that you are seeking.

Comment: As @Wrzlprmft suggested, I make it a general question about formalism

Comment: *I like to write one, and don't know this type of papers*: This is the real problem.  Before attempting to write an academic paper, one has to read a great many existing papers on the same subject, to understand how your work will fit into what is already known.  Once this is done, you will have a much better idea of how issues like this are usually handled.

Comment: @NateEldredge I wrote that to say my aim of asking this question, but it doesn't degrade the question. Now I am going to remove this last sentence. You are right, I read a lot, they don't usually say formalism, they say Project, tool, ... but my problem is that technical term for which I like to get help here, otherwise I should read some papers (not related to my work) about formalism

Comment: What field of computer science?

Comment: @JeffE software engineering or artificial intelligence

Comment: "Formalism" is a perfectly ordinary English word, used in its ordinary way. Did you look in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Formalism" is the practice of using strict and complete methods to define and analyze a model, usually an abstract, idealized model.  Every term is given precise a definition. Every variable, parameter, and factor is given a precise name and definition.  All assumptions are made explicit and are defined precisely.  Qualifiers (e.g. "there exists...", "there does NOT exist...") and quantifiers (e.g. "for any...", "for all...") are made explicit in relational and logical statements.  In formalisms based in logic and mathematics, there are often a set of existential and relational rules called "axioms" that are "given" (assumed to be true), and these axioms are used to prove other existential and relational statements or rules (theorems and lemmas).

It's common and convenient to use symbols and symbol statements rather than words -- i.e. single letters for variables, single shapes for operations, etc.  Depending on the formalism, these could be mathematical and/or logical symbols.

To qualify as a "formalism", the definitions, statements, and rules described above need to be a *complete* definition of the model and it's mechanisms, ideally with no redundancy or gaps.  Furthermore, a formalism should enable other researchers to reproduce the analysis that leads to the results *by following the formalism* ***literally***, and without recourse to any other context or information.  While intuition is useful to interpret a formalism and see the value of it in a given context, intuition is never called into the formalism itself.

Finally, a formalism is a *world unto itself*, in that it's meaning and interpretation do not depend on any connection or any context in the "real world".  Whether or not a formalism has any relevance to real world phenomena is a separate (and important) question.

---

Regarding paper structure using formalism, the following sections are common after the Introduction:

- General description, goals, and scope
- Definitions
- Assumptions
- Axioms
- Theorems and proofs
- Results
- Discussion (i.e. research implications relative to the goals of the model)

In addition, some papers have worked examples to illustrate the model and it's results in particular cases.  I find these very helpful to understand and visualize the model and it's significance.

Comment: Thank you! Then if I want to describe a tool and an scheme for a declarative program (like HTML) which is used in the tool to do something, is it called formalism? I guess no

Comment: No, it would not be a "formalism".  Describing a software tool, even when done in a complete and exact way, is usually called a "specification", not a formalism.  Likewise for a software program or algorithm.  As @jakebeal said, formalism is just a research tool.  It's useful and appropriate for some purposes, but not all.  If it's not appropriate or useful, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are making a common mistake of classification.  In your question, you speak of a formalism as the *goal* of a paper.  Instead, I would recommend thinking of formalism as a *tool* toward achieving some goal.

Since formalism is a tool, and not a goal, it can be presented in a number of different ways, as best serves its position within a larger framework.  To better illustrate this, Let me give a few examples of the use of formalism in a larger narrative from recent papers that I have published:

- Formalization used to extract and clarify the "important bits" of a complex model
- Formalization used to develop a new set of theoretical guarantees
- Formalization user to analyze the tradeoffs between a set of competing approaches
- Formalization used to create a predictive model for an experimental system

For each case, the way in which the formalism is best presented varies greatly (although in all cases I like to use certain presentation aids, such as creating a table of symbols).

I would thus recommend starting by asking the following questions:

1. What is the value of creating this formalism?
2. What evidence can be presented to demonstrate the value of the formalism?

When you have answered these questions, the arrangement of the formalism within the larger narrative of the paper can follow.

Comment: Can I say, by formalism you may mean an arrangement or structure or protocol or grammar for data, components, elements... to achieve something?

Comment: @Ahmad Some of these are; others are different types of formalizations.